# C++ Candidate Template Ignored error when passing lambda as argument for std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, std-function

This is a general, skeleton version of a template problem I'm having in C++.  I can't quite figure out how to get the `bar` function template to be recognized as a plausible candidate when invoked from `foo`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unordered_map>

template<class T>
std::unordered_map<std::string, T> getStr2TMap() {
  return {}; // suppose logic here is a bit more involved
}

template<class T>
std::unordered_map<int, T> getInt2TMap() {
  return {}; // suppose logic here is a bit more involved
}

template<class U, class T>
void bar(
  const std::function<void (std::unordered_map<U, T>&&)>& baz
) {
  if (rand() % 2 > 0) {
    baz(getInt2TMap<T>());
  } else {
    baz(getStr2TMap<T>());
  }
}

template<class T>
void foo(
  const std::unordered_map<std::string, T>& map1
) {
  bar([&map1](auto&& map2) {
    // do some things with map1 and map2
  });
}

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> myMap;
  foo<int>(myMap);
}
```

**EDIT**

Much simplified version of the code, same error.  I'm looking for solutions to the above version though, not this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

template<class T>
void foo(
  const std::function<void (std::unordered_map<int, T>&&)>& bar
) {
  std::unordered_map<int, T> myMap;
  bar(myMap);
}

int main() {
  foo([](auto&& m) {
  });
}
```

Comment: It looks like part of the problem here is that I need to explicitly pass a type arg when I call `foo`?  Is there any way to deduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown code attempts to deduce `T` and `U` for the following type

```
std::function<void (std::unordered_map<U, T>&&)>
```

The deduction attempt is for the lambda parameter passed to the template function:

```
[&map1](auto&& map2) {}
```

The problem is that a lambda is not a `std::function` of some kind. It is a:

> ...temporary object of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class
>   type, known as "closure" type,...

([Cite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda))

Put in another way, a lambda object is an instance of a class with an `operator()` that executes the lambda code (and captured objects get transmogrified into members of the unnamed class). As such, since it is not a `std::function`, it is not possible to deduce `std::function`'s types from it.

Since it is a callable type, it can be converted to a `std::function`, though:

```
bar(static_cast<std::function<void(std::unordered_map<std::string, T> &&)>>
      ([&map1](auto&& map2) {
          // do some things with map1 and map2
      }));
}
```

That'll get the `bar()` template function recognized.

But there's still a second problem with the shown code:

```
  if (rand() % 2 > 0) {
    baz(getInt2TMap<T>());
  } else {
    baz(getStr2TMap<T>());
  }
```

Depending on the roll of the dice, the code will attempt to pass either an unordered map of strings, or an unordered map of ints to `baz()`.

That's ...not going to work. At this stage of the game, `baz` is a `std::function` of some kind. It's not a template. As such, it can only take a parameter of one type.

If you add that `static_cast`, and make `bar()` a:

```
 baz(getStr2TMap<T>());
```

to match the fact that the caller is passing an unordered map of strings, the resulting code should compile.

What's happening inside your `bar()` is a separate issue. Using the `static_cast` answers the question of how to get the candidate template `bar` recognized.

Comment: the `rand()` thing was my attempt to approximate more involved logic where I don't actually know what the key type is.  In reality not going to have to handle 2 different key types, just one unknown one.  I guess I goofed on simplifying it here.

Answer (score 1):

Sam makes a good observation about how `U` is inconsistent in `bar`. But in your simple example, why go through all the trouble of `const std::function<void (std::unordered_map<int, T>&&)>&` when you could write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

template<class T, class Func>
void foo(
  Func bar
) {
  std::unordered_map<int, T> myMap;
  bar(myMap);
}

int main() {
  // needs the hint for T, since it isn't used anywhere
  foo<int>([](auto&& m) {
  });
}
```